# Java: prevent using high version APIs when compiling using a high version JDK but running on a low version JRE

Tags: java, compilation, runtime

I'm gradually migrating a project at work from Java **7 to 8**.

I'd like to do this in 2 steps - migrate the **build machines** and then the **run-time machines**.

BUT

even though the compiler args are set to `source=7` and `target=7`, it seems that when using JAVA 8 APIs, like `streams and Optional`, the compilation still passes successfully. Obviously, the code will **break** by a `ClassNotFoundException` when it will be executed on a Java 7 machine.

This is very surprising. **How can I protect against using high version APIs when running on the correctly specified low version JRE?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way, using the **`bootclasspath`** feature.

In the build machine, though the build is done by a Java 8 compiler, I'm specifying the **-bootclasspath** param, providing a Java 7 rt.jar.

Example(raw):

```
javac <all-other-params> -bootclasspath /usr/alik/jdk1.7.0_21-rt.jar
```

Maven example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>7</source>
        <target>7</target>
        <compilerArguments>
            <bootclasspath>/usr/alik/jdk1.7.0_21-rt.jar</bootclasspath>
        </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When a developer is trying to use a Java 8 API, like `Optional`, the compilation finally fails with the error: `cannot find symbol class Optional`.

Comment: See the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087200/can-i-compile-java-for-an-older-java-version-with-ant-with-a-newer-jdk-so-it-gen). Apart from a maven plugin like [Animal Sniffer](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/index.html), the `-bootclasspath` option is the best what you can get now. And hope for the `-release` option to make it into the Java 9.