# Can i compile java for an older Java version with ant with a newer JDK so it generates output when it compiles code that uses the newer API?

Tags: java, ant, compilation, java-8

I would like to only have JDK 8 installed on my system, and have the ant javac compile action create working classfiles for a java 6 environment.

This sort of works if I syntactically only use java 6 compliant code, but my code can access methods/classes of the java 8 API and still be java 6 compliant according to ant's compile action.

This is even the case when using the "javac" task attributes "source" and "target" set to java 6. I am aware that this generates the following warning: [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6. But this is not the type of warning that helps me detect if my code actually uses newly introduced API elements.

I need the compile action to somehow do something when the code that's being compiled tries to make use of java 8 API introduced methods/classes.

As an example: with java 6 compliant code I can access java.lang.reflect.Constructor.getParameters() if copmiled using JDK 8, which is a method inherited from a Java 8 introduced parent class Executable. When the code runs in a java 6 exeuction environment, executing that statement will result in a thrown NoSuchMethodException, unforseen and thusly unhandled as well. I need my ant compile action generate some different kind of output (a halt or a warning or something else) so that I can automate something on that.

Is there an ant-related solution for me in this scenario?

Comment: No. The bytecode wouldn't work, because that method isn't in earlier versions of Java.

Comment: “But this is not the type of warning that helps me detect if my code actually uses newly introduced API elements.”  Actually, I’m pretty sure it is.  The warning is telling you to use Java 6 classes when compiling, so you won’t inadvertently call newer methods.

Comment: Java 9 will plug one of the holes here, checking for use of newer APIs when compiling for an older release.  (There are also third-party tools that check for this, such as AnimalSniffer.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz: Great solution. Unless you need `-source 1.8 -target 1.8 -bootclasspath ${1.7}`, as in the case of `javac` → *RetroLambda* → *StreamSupport* pipe-line, where `javac` fails because of `LambdaMetafactory`. In such a case, it would be great to have the API (post-)check on the `*.class` files instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write:

> I am aware that this generates the following warning: [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6.

This warning points us toward the correct solution. In addition to the `-source` and `-target` options, use `javac`'s `-bootclasspath` option to specify a bootstrap class path pointing to the `rt.jar` of `1.6`. You do not have to have a complete JDK 1.6 on you computer; that jar, which contains the API classes, is sufficient.

Oracle has [further instructions and options for cross-compiling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCIJIEG) on its website.

Note that this issue is addressed by [JEP 247](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/247), which hopefully will make it into the Java 9 release. Then, there will be a `-release` compiler option, combining `-source`, `-target` and `-bootclasspath` with an appropriate file shipping with the JDK itself. So you don’t need to get that `rt.jar` from an older JDK anymore.

Comment: Just a warning: It won't work when what you need is `-source 1.8 -target 1.8 -bootclasspath ${1.7}`, like in the `javac` → *RetroLambda* → *StreamSupport* pipe-line. It will fail as soon as you use a lambda or a method-ref in the source, with: `cannot find symbol: method metafactory(...), location: interface LambdaMetafactory`. :o(

Comment: @charlie: for that purpose, you have to specify a bootclasspath containing the Java 7 API, e.g. `rt.jar`, *and* a folder/jar containing a dummy `LambdaMetafactory`, which only needs to contain declarations of the [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) members. For compiling, the methods don’t need to work. That’s all you need when you want to compile for Java 7. If you want to backport to even older versions, things get much more complicated…

Comment: Holger, thanks, nice hack, I had a similar plan: to extract the `LambdaMetafactory` (+ `LambdaConversionException`) from J8's `rt.jar`. It's not even needed on the `bootclasspath`, the build classpath is enough -- then lambdas compile just fine. But for a "production" setup, we'll probably go a less hacky way (e.g. with *Animal Sniffer*).

Comment: P.S.: Also, that hack still allows anyone to call the J8's `LMF` from a J7 code, however unlikely it is.

Answer (score 2):

You either have to code to Java 6 API or find back ports of the new libraries to package with your application

Answer (score 1):

You only real option for Java 6+ compatibility is to use the Java 6 compiler. The disk space you save is not worth the worry that it won't actually run on Java 6.

Comment: @grimmeld I suggest you have a continuous build system which compiles your code with the exact version you need it to once you check in the code.  Then there is no confusion as to which version was used. This is what we do for Java 7 modules.

Comment: @grimmeld in which case I would install Java 6 and use that for your build for this project. You can use environment variables like `JDK6_HOME` and `JDK8_HOME` in your build to ensure you are using the version you think you should.